# how to get value with in a loop and send to another page?

Tags: php

I want to get the value of `$sched->start_time` and `$sched->end_time` and send them into the `next_page.php`.

```
<?php 
 foreach($foo as $row){
 echo "
 <tr>
   <td>".$sched->start_time."</td>
   <td>".$sched->end_time."</td>
   <td class='add'><a class='add_sched' href='next_page.php'>add new</a></td></tr>";
 }
?>
```

Output will look like this

---

> | 7:30 | 8:30  | *add   |
>    | 8:30 | 9:30  | *add   |
>    | 9:30 | 10:30 | *add   |

and if I click on *add @ 8:30-9:30 that value will be send on the `next_page.php`
how should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
echo
...

 "<td class='add'>
   <a class='add_sched' href='next_page.php?start_time=".$sched->start_time."&end_time=".$sched->end_time."'>add new</a>
</td>"
```

In `next.php`

```
$start_time = $_GET['start_time'];
$end_time = $_GET['end_time'];
```